# Gift from a brother who is USA citizen but resides in India for over 2 years would like to gift to a brother in USA who is American citizen

Tags: united-states, taxes, india, money-transfer

1. Can a brother in India who is an American citizen but living in India for over 2 years send a gift to a brother who is an American citizen in the USA without any tax consequences in India or in the USA by him or a brother in the USA?
2. What is the maximum amount that can be gifted to a brother in the USA without paying Federal tax?
3. I have heard that a relative can GIFT a lifetime exclusion gift of $11.58 million without paying any tax in the USA. Is this correct?
4. What is the best way to transfer money? Can brother in the USA open up and account as an NRI in India, in say Bank of America or Chase bank and can transfer the money to the USA thru these banks?

Answer (score 1):

Partial answer: No. 3 is correct.

Note that **if** the **giving** brother is **in the US** then if the gift is **more than $14,000** he must **inform** the IRS about the gift, and deduct that amount from the $11.58M exclusion.